# React with TypeScript - turn Axios Get method into Generic Axios Get Method

Tags: generics, axios, react-typescript

I am trying to make my `axios Get` method into a `generic method`, so I can reuse it everywhere I need it.

I am having a bit of trouble on how to make it work. Let me show you some code

```
axios.get(`${urlUser}?userName=${getUserName()}`)
            .then((response: AxiosResponse<userProfile>) => {
                setProfile(response.data);
            })
```

This is the get method I am trying to convert to a generic method.
the Url and the state function `setProfile` could be passed in as parameters, but the `userProfile` model needs to be an generic

```
export const Get = <T>(url: string, setState: any, Response: T) => {
    axios.get(url)
            .then((response: AxiosResponse<T[]>) => {
                setState(response.data);
        })
}
```

Here is the generic converted code.
However, this could not work because in the `AxiosResponse`, I need to pass in some kind of model for the response.

I tried to add a generic `Response` parameter to the function, but it does not work to add the `Response` into the `AxiosResponse<>`

I dont think I am far off, any idea on how to fix this?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution

```
export const Get = <T,>(url: string, setState: any) => {
    axios.get(url)
            .then((response: AxiosResponse<T[]>) => {
                setState(response.data);
        })
}
```

the Get function, where its called

```
Get<userProfile>(`${urlUser}?userName=${getUserName()}`)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use generic like this way:

```
const { data: users } = await this.axios.get<User[]>('/users');

console.log(users);
```